# Cannot resolve keyword 'slug_iexact' into field. Choices are: Tag_Name, id, posts, slug

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am getting the following error:

```
FieldError at /tag/htc_phones/
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug_iexact' into field. Choices are: Tag_Name, id, posts, slug
```

models.py :

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    Tag_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,editable=True,max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Tag_Name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

views.py:

```
def tag_detail(request,slug):
    tag = Tag.objects.get(slug_iexact=slug)
    return render(request,'website_primary_html_pages/tag_detail.html',context={'tag':tag})
```

how to fix this problem , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a lookup, you use *two consecutive* underscores (so `__`):

```
def tag_detail(request,slug):
    tag = Tag.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)  # ← slug__iexact, not slug_iexact.
    return render(request,'website_primary_html_pages/tag_detail.html',context={'tag':tag})
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: thanks it work great , thanks for note , other question in my html page i want to show tag name that i added so i write this code   `<h4>{{mobile_posts.tag}}</h4>` but in my html page it show `blog_app.Tag.None` i want tag name why thay happen ?

Comment: @KokHyvv: because that is likely a `ManyToManyField`, you need `mobile_posts.tags.all`, but that will give you a `<QuerySet`, so you need to render it with `{% for mytag in mobile_posts.tags.all %}{{ mytag }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: hi can u ask you .. how to make pagination in views.py in tag_deatil ?

Comment: @KokHyvv: but here you show the detail of a single `tag`, hence there is nothing to paginate.

Comment: okay .. when i add some tag and add many and many record to this tag . the page will show all posts have this tag .. so in Tag page how to add pagination and if i can't what i must edit ?

Comment: @KokHyvv: then you create a queryset that looks like `other_tags = Tag.objects.filter(manytomanyfield=tag)` (with `manytomanyfield` the name of the `ManyToManyField`), you paginate this as in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function, and render the related tags with `{% for othertag in page_obj %} ... {% endfor %}`.

Comment: hello i tried many things but everything not work , i edit my code to this and i got error ,, please can you check it https://codeshare.io/adPkwR

Comment: @KokHyvv: is it possible to ask a new question? Add the relevant models and the (relevant parts) of the view.

Comment: yes sure thanks , this is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635038/unboundlocalerror-at-tag-htc-phones-local-variable-tag-referenced-before-ass