# UnboundLocalError at /Tag/HTC-Phones/ local variable 'tag' referenced before assignment - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am getting the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /Tag/HTC-Phones/
local variable 'tag' referenced before assignment
/home/pc/Desktop/django_stuff/blog_project/blog_app/views.py in tag_detail, line 86
```

models.py :

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    Tag_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,editable=True,max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Tag_Name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

class Mobile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag',blank=True,related_name='posts')
```

views.py :

```
from .models import Tag

def tag_detail(request,slug):
    tag = Tag.objects.filter(manytomanyfield=tag)
    return render(request,'website_primary_html_pages/tag_detail.html',context={'tag':tag})
```

the error in views in `tag = Tag.objects.filter(manytomanyfield=tag)`

how to fix this problem , thanks

Comment: So do you want to render the `Mobile`s or the `Tag`?

Comment: Tag and Mobile i have used `manytomanyfield` so i want add tags and use data from `Mobile model` at same time

Comment: yes, but the slug will normally only match one tag, since this is "detail view" of the `Tag`. So I guess then there is *one* tag, and a number of `Mobile`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the related `Mobile`s for a given tag with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Tag, Mobile

def tag_detail(request,slug):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug__iexact=slug)
    mobiles = Mobile.objects.filter(tag=tag)
    context = {
        'tag': tag,
        'mobiles': mobiles
    }
    return render(request, 'website_primary_html_pages/tag_detail.html', context)
```

In the template you render this with:

```
{% for mobile in mobiles %}
    <!-- render the mobile -->
    {{ mobile.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can also [*paginate* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function) the `mobiles` objects with:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Tag, Mobile

def tag_detail(request,slug):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug__iexact=slug)
    mobiles = Mobile.objects.filter(tag=tag)
    paginator = Paginator(mobiles, 25)  # ← 25 objects per page
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(request.GET.get('page'))
    context = {
        'tag': tag,
        'mobiles': mobiles,
        'page_obj': page_obj
    }
    return render(request, 'website_primary_html_pages/tag_detail.html', context)
```

Then you iterate over the `page_obj`:

```
{% for mobile in page_obj %}
    <!-- render the mobile -->
    {{ mobile.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

The section on [*Paginating a **`ListView`*** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview) contains information on how to render the links to the previous/next page.

Comment: hello i hope you are fine , can you help me with this problem , it's very hard  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636761/data-doesnt-appear-in-my-html-page-when-i-add-new-record-django