# data doesn't appear in my html page when i add new record - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

when i add new record from `admin panel` it should appear in html page , but it doesn't do that

how to fix it

models.py :

```
class BestArticals(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    url = models.URLField(default="",max_length=240)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py :

```
from .models import BestArticals

def Best_Articals(request):
    best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()
    context = {'best_posts' : best_posts}
    return render(request,'android/side_bar_good_posts.html',context=context)
```

html page :

```
  {% for post in best_posts %}

  <div class="card rounded mx-auto d-block" style="width: 18rem;margin-bottom:50px;border-color:#7952b3">
    
  <div class="card-body" id="mobile_design_card">
    <a href="{{post.url}}"><p class="card-text" id="mobile_design_card_name">{{ post.name }}</p></a>
  </div>
  <a href="{{post.url}}"><img src="{{ post.get_image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="290px" width="300px"></a>

  </div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
  {% endfor %}
```

- i didn't add `Best_Articals` in urls.py because i don't want create url for it , i just want show data in other html page from `side_bar_good_posts.html`

for example i add this line in other html page :

```
{% include 'android/side_bar_good_posts.html' %}
```

Comment: What happens when you refresh the page? How are you trying to display the data?

Comment: when i refresh the page nothing happen

Comment: i tried like my code .. i don't know what is the problem ... when i set url for page it show data normally but when i use it in other html page like {% include 'test.html' %} it don't work

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment... You should analyze how to works **include tag** and **view function**. Let me try to explain me, when you make request to some url, it calls to specific **view function** and the view return the processed data for this reason when you set url it works.
**Include tag** only add all text from in it in your file where you use *include tag*, for this when you add `include 'android/side_bar_good_posts.html'` only add plain text (html, css, js ) that contains *android/side_bar_good_posts.html* but in this point this file doesn't contains information about the post because your variable **best_posts** is empty, nothing call to your Best_Articals view to return **best_post**. You need to pass the additional context (best_post) to your template.
I.e. `{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}`

Or you could use context processor and then you can use {{best_post}} in all the templates.

Comment: thanks for your commenet .. can you explain more about this line ... {% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %} .... in my case what should i write after with .. i mean what is person and greeting

Comment: person and getting are variables you can read in your template ({{person}}, {{greeting}}). In your case you should pass best_posts = best_posts after "with"

Comment: i tried like this `{% include "android/side_bar_good_posts.html" with best_posts=best_posts %}`  but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you get the value for **best_post**?  you need to get the values first, similar to `best_posts = BestArticals.objects.all()` and then pass **best_post** using **with** in include tag.

Comment: if i set url for it and open browser then open url yes i get my data but it's don't load for loop when i use {%include%}

Comment: thanks for your help it helped me >> check my answer i forget add one line in views